# WORDPRESS Where to find advanced custom fields groups in phpmyadmin wp database?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I'm trying to create custom fields with custom validation manually but I don't know where to find the created custom fields, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ACF fields and groups are stored in the default **wp-posts** table with the post type **acf-field-group** for groups and **acf-field** for the fields. The acf-field post type are child posts of the acf-field-group post type.